# How to prove the following statement about convex hulls?

Tags: integer-programming, convex-hull

Consider $M$ finite sets of integer points $P_m$, $m=1,\ldots,M$. Let
$$A = \left\{x_m\in\operatorname{conv}P_m, m=1,\dots,M, \sum_{m=1}^MN_mx_m=0\right\}$$
and
$$B =\operatorname{conv}\left\{x_m\in P_m, m=1,\dots,M, \sum_{m=1}^MN_mx_m=0\right\}$$
where $N_m$ is a matrix of dimension compatible with $x_m$ and $\operatorname{conv}P_m$ is the convex hull of the points in $P_m$.

I was wondering if it is possible to prove that
$$B\subseteq A$$
and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be possible.

Firstly, let us see if we can establish that $A$ is convex. Take

\begin{align}X &= (x_1,\ldots,x_M)\in A\\Y&=(y_1,\ldots,y_M)\in A.\end{align}

Let $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$. Then

$$\lambda X + (1-\lambda) Y = (\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)y_1,\ldots,\lambda x_M + (1-\lambda)y_M).$$

Since \begin{align}N_1x_1 + \ldots + N_Mx_M &= 0\\N_1y_1 + \ldots + N_My_M &= 0,\end{align} we have
$$N_1(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) y_1) +\ldots+ N_M(\lambda x_M + (1-\lambda) y_M) = 0.$$

Also, $\forall i=1,\ldots,M, \lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i\in\operatorname{conv}(P_i)$.

Thus, convexity of $A$ is established.

$B$ is the convex hull of a subset of points of $A$. Let this subset be $K\subseteq A$.

So, $B = \operatorname{conv}(K)\subseteq\operatorname{conv}(A)=A$, since $A$ is convex.